# Pandas - access gouped levels in function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which is the result of a groupby function. I would now like to perform varied operations, based on the groupby levels:

```
    d = {'col1': ['foo','bar','foo','bar', 'baz','foo', 'baz', 'bar','bar'],
         'col2': ['a', 'b','c','a','b','c','a','a','b'], 
         'col3': [5,6,6,5,4,6,5,4,3]}

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    df
        col1    col2    col3
     0  foo     a       5
     1  bar     b       6
     2  foo     c       6
     3  bar     a       5
     4  baz     b       4
     5  foo     c       6
     6  baz     a       5
     7  bar     a       4
     8  bar     b       3

    df2 = df.groupby(['col1','col2']).count()
    df2['col4'] = ''
    df2
                      col3  col4
          col1  col2    
          bar   a     2    
                b     2    
          baz   a     1    
                b     1    
          foo   a     1     
                c     2
```

Now I want to write a function which will give me the mean of col3 in col4. Please note that my actual df2 has many different vals for col1 and col2 (ie. I need to access the [foo,bar,baz] grouping). I've been trying the varied ways of subindexing with no luck.

Comment: what do you mean by mean of col3? mean takes a `level` param if that is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ed said, you need to provide the level:

```
>>> df2.mean(level=0)
      col3
col1      
bar    2.0
baz    1.0
foo    1.5

>>> df2.mean(level=1)
          col3
col2          
a     1.333333
b     1.500000
c     2.000000
```